# Why are SIP and PyQt4 not getting along

Tags: python, pyqt4, python-sip

I do most of my work in Windows and have a good python27 set up like I like it.  I recently installed virtualBox and got a Ubuntu Machine running on it and am trying to get PyQt4 installed on it.  I installed from apt-get and updated everything, however, when I try to import from PyQt4

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore
```

I get a runtimeError:

```
RuntimeError: the sip module implements API v9.0 to v9.1 but the PyQt4.QtCore module requires API v8.1
```

I am sure this is a problem that I would have the knowledge base to solve in Windows, but my Linux inexperience is getting the better of me here and I have installed something incorrectly.  The error leads me to believe I have a SIP version that is too fancy for my PyQt version...anybody have any experience with this?

**Edit**:  If I try the import again after receiving the error it seems to work.  Doing this I obtained the version info.

```
cfg.pyqt_version_str
Out[9]: '4.9.3'
cfg.sip_version_str
Out[10]: '4.14.3-snapshot-55188026fe6d'
```

Not sure what all that snapshot business is about.

Comment: @gertvdijk: Where did you get that it is the "successor"? Keep in mind that Nokia sold off Qt to Digia which means the open-source aspects could still be a "?", while none of this has impacted Riverbanks course at all. One is just LGPL while the other is GPL. PyQt is actively maintained.

Comment: Possibly not in this case, but I have run into situations where I need it.  I.E. compatibility issues with Spyder during certain times in it's development for one.  PySide can't implement PyQt until PyQt comes out of course

Comment: Do you know what version of PyQt you have installed vs the sip version?

Comment: well, that's where me not being great at Linux hurts me...I just did a apt-cache search pyqt
sudo apt-get install python-qt4

Comment: Did you install sip manually or did it come from apt-get? For some reason, it used the development snapshot of sip 4.14.3 which isn't probably the best idea because your PyQt is not the latest version

Comment: I downloaded it with pip and then it failed so I compiled it from source

Comment: ya so you probably have some conflicting version now. Can you try and remove it all and just take one route or another?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just tested an install of sip/pyqt via `apt-get` and it installed:

- sip 4.12.4
- PyQt4 4.8.5

The sip version you are reporting is a development snapshot. I recommend removing all of it, doing a `sudo apt-get update` and then `sudo apt-get install python-sip python-qt4` again.

Otherwise, you can do the latest stable version from source:

- [sip 4.14.2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/files/sip/sip-4.14.2/sip-4.14.2.tar.gz)
- [PyQt4 4.9.6](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/files/PyQt4/PyQt-4.9.6/PyQt-x11-gpl-4.9.6.tar.gz)

If you have mixed installations, try and remove all of that. With pip you can do `pip remove sip`. Or you can go into a python shell and find out where it is, then manually remove it:

```
$ python
>>> import sip
>>> print sip 
# path to sip
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use Qt 4.7, these version work together (build worked on x86_64 Centos6)

```
    PyQt 4.10.4
    SIP 4.15.5
    QT 4.7.4
```

If you need Qt 4.8, these versions worked together for a build of PyQt4:

```
    PyQt 4.11
    SIP 4.16
    QT 4.8.x
```

Using these steps to build PyQt4:

```
    python configure-ng.py -g
    make
    make install
```